# Using substring of file name to create new variable in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a directory with a set of .rds files containing dataframes:

```
files <- c("file_2022-11-30.rds", "file_2022-12-01.rds")
```

I want to read each file into a list and then assign a new column to each dataframe in the list that contains a piece of name of the file it was loaded in from (the date). I know how to do this with a for loop, but I'm looking for a concise solution. I'm sure there's a way to do this with lapply, but this doesn't work:

```
library(dplyr)

df_list <- lapply(files, readRDS) %>%
  lapply(FUN = function(x) mutate(date = as.Date(stringr::str_sub(files[x], start = -14, end = -5)))) %>%
bind_rows()
```

Desired output would look something like this:

```
   var1       date
1     1 2022-11-30
2     2 2022-11-30
3     2 2022-11-30
4     1 2022-11-30
5     2 2022-11-30
6     2 2022-12-01
7     1 2022-12-01
8     2 2022-12-01
9     1 2022-12-01
10    2 2022-12-01
```

Comment: @akrun true, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `as.Date` on the `files` and convert it to `Date` class.  Then loop over the `files`, read with `readRDS`, `cbind` the 'dates' in `Map` and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
dates <-  as.Date(files, format = "file_%Y-%m-%d.rds")
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(files, readRDS), dates = dates))
```

---

Or if we want to use `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2_dfr(files, dates, ~ readRDS(.x) %>%
          mutate(dates = .y))
```

---

In the OP's code, the `files[x]` wouldn't work because `x` is not an index, it is the `list` element i.e. the output from `readRDS` and there is no information about the `files` in the `x`.  Instead, we can do this once within the single `lapply`

```
lapply(files, function(x)      
   readRDS(x) %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(stringr::str_sub(x, start = -14, end = -5)))) %>%
   bind_rows
```